# selenium webdriver sendkeys issue on IE - frame moves/shifts

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using  webdriver with IE 9.

When I exceute a "sendkeys" on my webelement the content of the relevant frame moves/shifts upwards.

I debugged my code and the strange behaviour occurs exactly in that moment when this line is executed:

searchTerm.sendKeys(searchString);

"searchTerm" is a Webelement, which is created by the PageFactory in that class. In my case it is a "textbox".

Although it is possible to write text into my textbox, I am struggling with that strange behaviour and would like to get rid of this. The problem is that the affected frame move above other existing frame and elements...

I dont have this problem when using firefox...

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

If you're referencing to that it scrolls the content of a frame strangely, then that's something you'll have to live with. WebDriver had (and sometimes still has) serious trouble with interacting with elements when it had to scroll to them, that's why there's some aggressive scrolling involved. It should be harmless since it doesn't actually change anything.

If it really changes the page layout, then that's a problem which should be closely examined. File a bug at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/entry or post some relevant testcase here.

Comment: The problem is that in my case it does not  change the page layout itself but I am no longer able to perform 'click' on webelements which are no longer seen due to the scroll phenomenom.
I can do a workaround and use 'sendkeys' on that 'hidden' 
webelement to re-scroll, but that seems quite odd to me...
Any ideas or suggestions on that? Thanks, Thomas

Comment: Now that sounds like a true pickle. It is strange that you can't click the elements, they should be re-scrolled to, too. But yeah, sometimes even the newest WebDriver just behaves like it did indeed click, but it didn't. Is this the case, or is WebDriver throwing any error? What sometimes helps (but is awful) is resizing the window, so that the elements are outside the window (and not just outside sight, but hidden behind something in the window) - then they should be definitely scrolled to.
If anyone has anything better, shoot, we all want to know!